# How can I log into the desktop environment as Root on a new mac running 10.6 or 10.7 without creating a user account?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, command-line, login

Under Mac OS 10.5, you could boot a fresh-out-of-the-box Mac into single user mode, mount /, set the root password, and touch .AppleSetupDone - this would allow you to log into the desktop environment as the root user without ever creating a 501 user. I've never been able to do this under 10.6 or 10.7, however. Has anyone been able to do this **without** first creating a traditional user account?

Many thanks!

Comment: what happens when you boot into single user mode when you first start up after the initial clean install?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use SUM by holding Cmd + S when booting up.  If I recall correctly from the last time I did it, that should automatically give you root.